# Reference for the proof of this lemma. (Double group trick)

Tags: galois-theory

I am reading from "Topics in Galois Theory" by Serre.

[image]

I want to study the proof of this lemma. He has not provided the proof.
Kindly mention some reference where I can read the proof.

It would be great if someone sketch the proof here.

One more thing, I want to clarify is the following

When he says fixed field $K_{1}$ of $H$  is rational, what does he mean ?